# Objective C - NSOpenPanel is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to declare `NSOpenPanel` in my code but it is not working and the Xcode can't find it, is there any reference or library to download before using it ?
My Xcode version is 7.3

Answer (score 1):

NSOpenPanel is only available for MacOS and not available for iOS. Anyway you can find the [reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/index.html)

Comment: oh ok, do you know what is the equivalent of it in the objective C ?

Comment: Basically all apps are sandboxed so you cannot access files anything outside your app sandbox. So there is no concept of opening a window where you can select any file which you can import into your app. Do google about app sandbox concept. Good luck